# A neighborhood of a 2-disc $D\subset\Bbb R^4$ that tapers off towards the boundary?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds, simplicial-complexes

I am given a PL 2-disc $D\subset\Bbb R^4$ (everything PL from here on) and I need a "neighborhood" $N\simeq B^4$ (PL-homeomorphic to a 4-ball) so that $\partial N\cap D=\partial D$.
If I got this right, then since $D$ is collapsible a regular neighborhood [1] will be a 4-ball; but unfortunately it contains $\partial D$ in its interior.

> **Question:** Can one tweak the theory of regular neighborhoods to give the desired neighborhood?

Another approach: it should be possible to "push the not locally flat parts" of $D$ to the boundary, so there should be a tubular neighborhood $T$ of $\mathrm{int}(D)$ [2]. Does this work in PL? Do we have $T\simeq\mathrm{int}(D)\times B^2$? If so, I believe I can make it taper off towards the boundary and take the closure.

---

- [1] Rourke, Sanderson, "Introduction to Piecewise-Linear Topology", Chapter 3
- [2] Brown, "Locally flat imbeddings of topological manifolds"

Answer (score 2):

Pick a triangulation of $\mathbb R^4$ which contains $D$ as a subcomplex, make two barycentric subdivisions, and then pick the closure of all the simplexes that intersect the interior of $D$. This could be a promising candidate.

Comment: While I agree that this is a promising candidate, I can't think of any standard tool that tells me that this is a 4-ball. E.g. let $D'$ be the subcomplex of $D$ obtained by deleting all triangles at the boundary, and assume that this is still a 2-disc. Is the neighborhood you describe a regular neighborhood of $D'$? I am not sure. $D$ could be weird at the boundary.